# How I can change the "return" button name to search in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

How I can change the "return" button name to search in an iphone app using xcode

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by changing the `returnKeyType` property of any control conforming to the [`UITextInputTraits`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html) protocol.

For example:

```
myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
```